# Taking values from a windows form application, and passing them back to the main method

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I am working on my final project, and I have a hit a wall. The arrays that are created and defined from the Form are being sent to the Main method, but I cannot further alter them later.

```
public string[] ShipTypes
    {
        get
        {
            string[] ships = new string[6];
            ships[0] = "Galaxy Class";
            ships[1] = "Galaxy Class";
            ships[2] = "Galaxy Class";
            ships[3] = "Galaxy Class";
            ships[4] = "Galaxy Class";
            ships[5] = "BattleCruiser";
            return ships;

        }
    }
```

but after I go to change the values

```
public void verifyButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
if (shipSelected1 == birdOfPrey || shipSelected1 == battleCruiser)
        {
            kShips++;
            if (shipSelected1 == birdOfPrey)
            {
                birdCount++;
                ShipTypes;
                ShipNames[0] = name1.Text;
                ShipShields[0] = shieldValue1;

            }
            else
            {
                battleCount++;
                ShipTypes[0] = battleCruiser;
                ShipNames[0] = name1.Text;
                ShipShields[0] = shieldValue1;
            }
        }
```

nothing happens at all, it keeps the original values from the initalization

Comment: `ShipTypes[0] = battleCruiser;` creates a new array, changes one value in it, and then *throws that array away forever*. Next time you do anything with ShipTypes, you get another newly created and initialized array. This happens because your code does what you told it to do. Tip: Read your own code *one line at a time* and think about what each line does. Don’t just stare at the whole screen; that’s useless. Consider each detail in turn.

Comment: @EdPlunkett

Ok, but I have the same issue if I use 'SetValue(birdOfPrey, 0);'

Comment: Did you make any effort to understand what I told you? Did you even read it? Did you read what Gene told you in his answer? It’s the same thing I told you. Simple problem, simple solution. I’ve no idea what SetValue() is; do you think I’m sitting next to you?

Comment: Put a breakpoint in the `get` for `ShipTypes`. It’s called every time you index the property. Every time.

Comment: I suppose I am not quite understanding why even if I am trying to change the value later on that it stays stuck there. is there a way to pass the value back to the `get` during the button action? The reason I ask is because that portion of the code was pre-defined, and the button event is the side I have been working on.

What do you mean by breakpoint?

Comment: The get is utterly, hopelessly broken. Easy fix, but it must change. If you are not quite understanding, try paying attention to what I’m telling you. Sadly I haven’t time to pursue this further. I wish you success.

Comment: I am sorry, Ed, I don't mean to be so ignorant, but I am learning C# as my first language, and there are certain things that I still do not comprehend yet.

Comment: Siide note, why not use an [enum](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/enum) instead of using strings for the ship type? It will prevent you from shooting yourself in the foot. You might use `"GalaxyClass"` instead of `"Galaxy Class"`, for instance. It will also give more IDE support, so when you're typing out what ship value to use, it will give auto complete and such. Also, if it has to do with user input, you can easily use enums to create a dropdown menu. This also prevents the user from entering something invalid or having to memorize all the ship ty

Answer (score 4):

ShipTypes's `get` definition guarantees that, regardless of what you set the value of that array, return that local `ships` array you created. Change your `get`.

*
When accessing a property, the `get` body is executed. When passing a value to a property, the `set` body is executed. Within the ShipTypes's `get` body, that `ships` array is created and returned. You are not getting returning what you need.

I would define:

```
public string[] _shipTypes;
public string[] ShipTypes
{
    get
    {
        if (_shipTypes == null)
        {
            _shipTypes = new string[6];

            _shipTypes[0] = "Galaxy Class";
            _shipTypes[1] = "Galaxy Class";
            _shipTypes[2] = "Galaxy Class";
            _shipTypes[3] = "Galaxy Class";
            _shipTypes[4] = "Galaxy Class";
            _shipTypes[5] = "BattleCruiser";

            return _shipTypes;
        }
        else return _shipTypes;
    }
    set => _shipTypes = value;
}
```

Comment: I suppose I am not quite understanding why even if I am trying to change the value later on that it stays stuck there. is there a way to pass the value back to the `get` during the button action? The reason I ask is because that portion of the code was pre-defined, and the button event is the side I have been working on.

Comment: I added more to my answer.